# Difference between these two jquery expressions?

Tags: jquery

What's the difference between:

```
$('#my-dropdown-id', 'option:selected')
```

and

```
$('#my-dropdown-id option:selected')
```

Comment: @s.kuznetsov ???

Comment: I just realized my problem... I just reversed the parameters on the first one.

Comment: I should probably just delete this question, lol. But I am actually curious if there is a difference between the two (assuming I hadn't reversed it) so I'll leave this up for a few more minutes to see if anyone comments on that.

Answer (score 2):

Passing two arguments means that the selected elements need to

- match the first argument selector
- be a descendant of the second selector

Passing a single argument with a space between two non-space words indicates that the first one must be an ancestor of the second.

So, your two examples do very similar things, only reversed.

`$('#my-dropdown-id', 'option:selected')` will select elements that match `#my-dropdown-id` which are descendants of an `'option:selected'`.

`$('#my-dropdown-id option:selected')` will select elements that match `'option:selected'` which are descendants of a `#my-dropdown-id`.

Comment: I think I understand, but the use of "or" in the first bullet point throws me off. You mean that the selection logic uses an "or" which results in both the drop down element "and" the selected option being returned. Right?

Comment: Yes, it's like `element.matches('#my-dropdown-id') || element.matches('option:selected')`

Comment: Whoa... now you raise another question! I had believed that the second parameter would only include elements that are descendants of the first parameter. Is that not the case?

Comment: Oops, you're right, I thought it did something else. So your two snippets are actually pretty similar - the two different sections indicate an ancestor-child relationship in both cases - but one is the reverse of the other.

Comment: Yep, I realized that right after my last comment, but unfortunately SO wasn't letting me see your answer any longer at the time (no idea why not) so I couldn't respond again. My whole problem was just that I had the parameters backwards.